# Windows server vs Synology

Tags: windows, synology, microsoft-access

I do network support for SMEs and a client decided to move away from cloud storage/backup and simple file sharing between Windows terminals and install a server.

Requirements are data encryption, MS Access database sharing with concurrent users, data backups and migration from cpanel email. Also, they would like encrypted remote connections (I am thinking of implementing an openssl certificate structure).

Based on the above and your experience in server maintenance, reliability, scalability and versatility, which of the following would you suggest:

1. Lenovo ThinkServer TS150
2. Dell PowerEdge T30
3. Synology DS918+

Is it after all a choice of hardware or software that will enable me to host all those different things on the same server?

Thank you!

Comment: From your needs I will chose to go with Windows server because. You need more a Server than a NAS. In addition, if you know windows, then sinology that is based on linux may be difficult. Also synology not have port for monitor to connect if something go wrong, so it’s not so simple to make a lot there and take the risk to hung out and lose all of them.